# How to obtain the latest item with specific attributes in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I've created a table with items like these:

```
[{
    device_id: '2',
    timestamp: 1498331237262
    gateway: 'gateway1',
    temperature: 20,
    humidity: 30,
    pressure: 101049,
    lat: 2,
    long: 1
},
{
    device_id: '2',
    timestamp: 1498331237261,
    gateway: 'gateway1',
    temperature: 20,
    humidity: 30,
    pressure: 101049
}]
```

Primary partition key: `device_id` (String)

Primary sort key: `timestamp` (Number)

I'm trying to obtain the latest (by `timestamp`) item that has the `lat` and `long` attributes.

My current broken attempt looks like this:

```
const params = {
    TableName: 'device_telemetry',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'device_id = :id AND ',
    ProjectionExpression: '#lat, #lng, #ts',
    FilterExpression: 'attribute_exists(#lat) AND attribute_exists(#lng)',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#lat': 'lat',
        '#lng': 'long',
        '#ts': 'timestamp'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':id': row['device_id'].toString(),
        ':startDate': row['departure_date'].getTime()
    },
    ScanIndexForward: false,
    Limit: 1
};
if (row['eta'] === null) {
    params.KeyConditionExpression += '#ts >= :startDate';
} else {
    params.KeyConditionExpression += '#ts BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate';
    params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':endDate'] = row['eta'].getTime();
}

const onResult = (res) => {
    console.info('devices res for: ', row['device_id'], res);
    if (res.Items.length > 1) {
        console.info(res.Items);
        throw new Error('Query returned more than 1 item: ' + params);
    }
    return res.Items[0];
};

console.info('query: ', params);
docClient.query(params).promise().then(onResult);
```

I understand that by `ScanIndexForward: false, Limit: 1` operate on the result obtained after the `KeyConditionExpression` is executed and after that the `FilterExpression` is ran, which means that in the 1st step I'll possibly get an item without the required attributes and then it gets filtered out.

What is the best way to do this? I'm a beginner with NoSQL concepts and I know that I also have to take in consideration the bucket distribution of data, besides getting the correct results.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just increase the limit to a sensible value, and repeat the query until result has at least one item?

Comment: I'm trying to minimize the amount of work, which means queries sent to the database and number of extra items transferred as a result. All the extra work causes extra time spent in the lambda functions and is not using the db resources efficiently, and all these end up being charged by Amazon.

Comment: I've ended up using your suggestion, increasing the limit to 10, but also removing the useless FilterExpression and doing the check for the attribute existence in the result handler.

I don't think I can mark your comment as an answer 

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky solution, but I can't think of any other way you can avoid doing more than 1 query for your need:

You can encode presence or absence of lat+long into the timestamp by adding a prefix. Example: "withCoord_timestamp". This will allow you to modify your range key query so that you no longer need filter expression, therefore you'll always get 1 result.

Comment: Seems that NoSQL databases involve hacks and workarounds a lot of time for things that just work in SQL databases 
I'm considering switching this single table that I have from DynamoDB to PostgreSQL.

Thanks for the help.